# What is the difference between 'necesitado', 'necesito' and 'necesario'?

Tags: uso-de-palabras, diferencias-regionales, significado, españa

I often need to express a **necessity** of something in my speech.

I know more options:

- the adjective [necesitado](http://www.wordreference.com/es/en/translation.asp?spen=necesitado)
- the verb [necesitar](http://www.wordreference.com/es/en/translation.asp?spen=necesito)
- the adjective [necesario](http://www.wordreference.com/es/en/translation.asp?spen=necesario)

Can you point out the differences among them? I am especially interested in the usage like:

> **es** nece[...]

If you are not from Spain please mention it in your answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The short answer is easy, because it's pretty much the same as English, altough there can be some differences.

- Necesitado = needed (adj.) or needy.
- Necesitar = need (v.)
- Necesario = neccesary (adj.)

So, if you want to express neccesity, it's directly:

> Es **necesario** que [...]

Which means 'It's neccesary to [...]' or '[...] is neccesary / required'.

This sentence is very frequent. For example:

> Es necesario actuar pronto <sub>It's neccesary to act soon</sub> = Action is required soon.

---

As you can see, this is very different to the others:

- 'Necesitar' is just the verb:

> Yo necesito <sub>I need</sub>

- 'Necesitado' can refer to the participle (I have needed); but it's more usually used as *needy*.

> Esto es para los más necesitados <sub>This is for the neediest</sub>

Comment: The one key difference I've seen, in comparison with English, would be that the phrase "Item X is needed" would be expressed as "Se necesita cosa X" (or possibly "Cosa X es necesaria").  // I'm not aware of any differences in usage by region, for this family of words.